# Move 2D saved points to compensate for 3D perspective change when camera pans and tilts

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, projection

I am drawing a restricted area by creating points and plotting the resulting polygon as an overlay on a camera video feed. The camera can only pan and tilt, and those defined points must move accordingly, so they seem to be virtually attached to the real-world area I highlighted.

New points are always created at the center of the image. I aim the camera exactly where I want a new point to be created and click "create". Then I move the camera somewhere else and click "create" again. I repeat until I have a polygon.

[image: Defined restricted area]

I am using stepper motors to pan and tilt the camera, so I can shift the plot's X and Y origin accordingly so they seem to "stick" to the real-world object I created them on.

The problem is:

It only works correctly for 1 point, at the center of the screen, if I just pan OR tilt the camera. Previous points that are elsewhere on the screen don't adapt to the perspective change, so the shape is wrong.

[image: Wrong shape]

What's the simplest solution? Object depth information is irrelevant to me, I just need the 2D visual feedback to see the restricted area.

Comment: you don't have the distance value so you can't calculate the new 2D position

Comment: Are you sure about that? Won't the lower side of the screen "expand" and the upper side "contract" the same amount when tilting the camera up regardless of the distance to the object?

Comment: the restricted area is a 3D shape, might not even be a plane, apply the perspective transformation to calculate the 2D/screen coordinates, who says you define the coordinates in a CW or CCW direction